# Consuming Picasa API

Tags: jquery, api, picasa

I'm having difficulties with consuming API from Google Picasa service.

Let's say i wan't to display this values via jquery:

```
<entry>
<id>
    https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/userID/albumid/albumID/photoid/5813338978197482482
</id>
<exif:tags>
    <exif:time>1203311251000</exif:time>
    <exif:imageUniqueID>uniqueID</exif:imageUniqueID>
</exif:tags>
<media:group>
    <media:content url="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/Penguins.jpg" height="384" width="512" type="image/jpeg" medium="image"/>
    <media:credit>user</media:credit>
    <media:description type="plain"/>
    <media:keywords/>
    <media:thumbnail url="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/s72/Penguins.jpg" height="54" width="72"/>
    <media:thumbnail url="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/s144/Penguins.jpg" height="108" width="144"/>
    <media:thumbnail url="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/s288/Penguins.jpg" height="216" width="288"/>
    <media:title type="plain">Penguins.jpg</media:title>
</media:group>
</entry>
```

No problems when reading values from entry tree, but hassle starts with exif:tags or media:group.
This is function for reading xml

```
$(xml).find('entry').each(function()
    {
        var item = ""
        item += "<li style='float:left;'>";
        item += $(this).find('title').text()    
        item += "</li>";
        $(".albums").append(item);
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there a question here? http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: how to read values inside media:group or exif:tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal ball time! I'm *guessing* you are trying to do something like this:

```
var $xml = $(/* get xml string from somewhere */);
var $entryId = $xml.find('entry > id'); // works
var $entryExifTags = $xml.find('entry > exif:tags'); // doesn't work
```

This is because [some characters, including `:`, have special meaning in jQuery selectors. Therefore you need to escape them](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F):

```
var $entryExifTags = $xml.find('entry > exif\\:tags');
```

Comment: Correct, i also managed to read those values with .children(foo\\:bar). now how to read values like <exif:time> or <exif:imageUniqueID>?

Comment: Same way. Just escape the colon.